# Is it possible to prevent unintentional re-dialling from Call History?

Tags: phone-app, call-history

I often unintentionally tap an item in the Call History list and that starts to re-dial the caller. I usually intended to tap the icon to view the duration of the call, but it is all too easy to tap the name or number instead. Is there anyway of changing that behaviour so that it doesn’t automatically re-dial the caller? If that isn’t possible, is it possible to have it prompt me for confirmation before re-dialling?

If it is significant, I am using Call History with Android 2.2 (Froyo) and HTC Sense.

Comment: My way of preventing this is by using Google Voice. Any time I'm about to make a call it gives me a choice of using my real number or Google Voice number. It's helped prevent some accidental calls before...  I would think there would be an application designed for this.

Comment: @BryanDenny I do the same thing, works quite well to prevent pocket dials. Only problem I've found is that it gimps occasionally, seems to be related to spotty coverage, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [Call Confirm](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.nanabit.callconfirm) app. This application is going to ask you whether to call or Hangup the contact what you touched on Call History.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, although I haven’t actually tried it yet. I’m a bit surprised that there isn’t an optional ‘call confirm’ prompt built into Android. It would seem like an obvious feature to include, for those of us who have clumsy fingers.